# Define multiple variables of same type in one line in Julia?

Tags: julia

In C++ you can write:

```
double x = 0.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0;
```

instead of:

```
double x = 0.0; double y = 0.0; double z = 0.0;
```

to define three variables of the same type, `double` in this example.

In Julia, the analogous would be:

```
x::Float64 = 0.0, y::Float64 = 0.0, z::Float64 = 0.0
```

Is there a syntactic sugar, like the above for C++, allowing me to omit the the three type specifiers, replacing them with just one when they are all the same?

**Note:** I know I can just write

```
x = y = z = 0.0
```

and let Julia infer the type. This is not what I want. I want to state explicitly that the types of `x,y,z` are constant.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the following doesn't declare those as variables in Julia

```
x::Float64, y::Float64, z::Float64
```

At least based on my investigation, you'd need something more like:

```
local x::Float64 = zero(Float64)
local y::Float64 = zero(Float64)
local z::Float64 = zero(Float64)
```

There is no syntactic sugar for doing that, AFAIK, forcing a particular type is not that common or necessary in Julia.

EDIT: I should be clearer, esp. after @dpsanders comment below, that I don't feel this is something that should normally ever be done in Julia, and even though type assertions can be useful for performance reasons in limited cases, using them so much you want syntactic sugar or a macro to shorten the code seems like a case of premature optimization.

If you really want to do that a lot, you can write a macro to take care of it for you, like the following:

```
macro dcl(T, args...)
    r = quote end
    for var in args
        push!(r.args, :( local $(esc(var))::$T = zero($T)) )
    end
    r
end
```

I'm sure some Julian with more macro-"fu" than me can do a much better job, but it does seem to work, in my testing, i.e.:

```
@dcl(Float64, x, y, z)
```

Edit:  The following demonstrates that the syntax doesn't declare any variables at all, just constrains the types of variables taken from the enclosing scope:

```
julia> function testdecl()
           x::Float64, y::Int, z::String
           println(x, y, z)
       end
testdecl (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype testdecl()
Variables:
  #self#::#testdecl

Body:
  begin  # REPL[107], line 2:
      (Core.typeassert)(Main.x,Main.Float64)::Float64
      (Core.typeassert)(Main.y,Main.Int)::Int64
      (Core.typeassert)(Main.z,Main.String)::String # REPL[107], line 4:
      return (Main.println)(Main.x,Main.y,Main.z)::Any
  end::Any
```

I'm wondering if there may also be a bug here, looking  at the following:

```
julia> function testdcl()
           println(y)
           x::Float64, y::String
           x = 1
           println(x)
       end
testdcl (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y = 1.234
1.234

julia> testdcl()
1.234
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
 in testdcl() at ./REPL[131]:2
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:226

julia> @code_warntype testdcl()
Variables:
  #self#::#testdcl
  x::Union{}

Body:
  begin  # REPL[131], line 1:
      (Main.println)(Main.y)::Any # REPL[131], line 2:
      (Core.tuple)((Core.typeassert)(x::Union{},Main.Float64)::Union{},(Core.typeassert)(Main.y,Main.String)::String)::Union{}
  end::Union{}
```

Comment: Actually `x::Float64` does seem to work, e.g. inside a function. But I have never (?) seen people actually using this kind of thing in real Julia code.

Comment: Try with what I had above in the function, from the OP, with 3 variables "declared", separated by commas.  If you look the result with `@code_warntype`, you'll see it isn't at all doing "declarations", it seems to be treating that as creating a tuple, with the types of the values constrained, and looks for the values of those variables *outside* of the function (which is why adding `local` is important if you really want a declaration).

Comment: OK, doesn't seem to be making a tuple, but it still doesn't "declare" a variable in the function.

Comment: Try with semicolons instead of commas?

Comment: That makes the type assertions work (you do get `x::Float64` when you try `@code_warntype`), but again, they aren't declarations of any sort, the scope of the variable is determined by the very difficult "soft-scoping" rules of Julia.

Comment: You're right, I updated my question to include values for the variables. "Declare" was probably a poor choice of a word (sorry, I come from a C++ background). The macro is nice (+1)

Comment: Yes, that will avoid the "soft-scoping" problems.  Also, for Julia, it would be better to have a semicolon instead of a comma (which seems to cause some strange problems at least in my testing)

Comment: `x::Float64` is a type *assertion*, and will throw an error if `x` happens not to be `Float64` at that point in the program.

Comment: Actually, that's not true.  The type assertion (rather unintuitively) affects *all* assignments to that variable in that function, even ones that occur before the line with the type assertion, similarly to how, in the absence of "local" or "global", the scope that a variable belongs to in a function is determined by whether the compiler determines it has been assigned to within the function. Also, it's not based on the type, the error occurs if a checked conversion fails (so `3.0` being assigned to a variable that has been asserted to be `Int` works fine, but `2.5` raises an error).

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't have types in Julia. *Values* have types.

But you can use `const` to ensure that a variable cannot be assigned a value of a different type. Here's one way, though it may not be the most concise:

```
const a, b, c = (zeros(Float64, 3)...)
```

Edit: But are you sure this is what you really want? Julia is a dynamically typed language, and what you're asking is something you normally do in a statically typed language.

Comment: While what you said is true, variables can still be typed. See `function g(); local x::Int; x = 2.0; x; end`, which returns 2 and not 2.0.

Comment: I think that's not so much that the variable is typed, but rather that a type assertion is placed on it, which makes sure that whenever that variable is assigned to a checked conversion is done (which may be a noop, for example, assigning something already known to be of the same type)

Comment: Isn't the difficulty and subtlety of this just an indication that it's not a useful way to think in Julia?

Comment: I think type assertions can be useful in some situations for performance reasons, when you may  want to assign something to a variable from a function that is not type stable.